# Find in all text using the re.search in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, search, printing

Thank you for coming.

### This is my code.

```
import re
content = '가나다라,456456 show, 가나다라<>'
a = re.search("[^a-zA-Z<>]+", content)
print(a.group())
```

---

```
Output : 가나다라,456456.
```

but I want this

```
Output : 가나다라,456456 , 가나다라
```

In other words, I want to search the full text .
What can i do? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `re.findall` in-order to get all the matches. `re.search` must return only the first match.

```
re.findall(r"[^a-zA-Z<>]+", content)
```

**Example:**

```
>>> import re
>>> content = '가나다라,456456 show, 가나다라<>'
>>> ''.join(re.findall("[^a-zA-Z<>]+", content))
'가나다라,456456 , 가나다라'
```